# youTube External Controls

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to get external controls for a youTube player to work. I think i'm not accessing the correct object in my function. I have set up the button and tried to get my function working. Using the [Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Playback_controls) are slightly confusing here as I am new to JS. Any advise or examples using my set on how i can get my external controls to function?

Thanks in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/qKsXL/8/

```
  // 6. Controls
  function playVideo() {
    event.target.playVideo();
    document.id("play").addEvent('click', function() {
    player.playVideo();
});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend learning more about JavaScript. There's a [good course here at Code Academy](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript).

So, here's what you're actually doing in your function:

1. Play the video
2. Add an event handler to some element with the ID "play" (is this syntax correct? I don't think this is a real function - you are thinking of getElementById()). The event handler play the video

You want to add the event handler when you initialize the script, NOT in the body of the function which is never called.

Comment: Thank you Ikai! The Code Academy and your comments were very helpful. I will post my functioning controls as soon as i get them working. Thanks!